# Does a non-deterministic Turingmachine reach every possible result?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

I have problems to imagine a non-deterministic Turingmachine.
Let's make an example: There is the problem of a Vertexcover. Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph and $k\geq 0$. The question is whether there is a vertexcover $C$ of size $|C|\leq k$. My book says that this problem is in $NP$, because a Turingmachine could just guess a subset $C\subset V$ with $|C|\leq k$ and check in polynomial time, whether we have a vertex cover.
If it guesses the set $C$ randomly, it could be possible that it does not work. So it just guesses another $C$.
My question: Will it guess **every** possible pair $(C,k)$? In other words, is it possible that the machine is stuck in an infinite loop by always guessing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-deterministic machine finds the solution "by magic": whenever there is a decision to be taken, it immediately takes the right one so that the search for a solution essentially amounts to the verification of the solution. There is no randomness involved and the machine is run once on the given problem.

Comment: So if there is a solution to the problem, the nondet TM will right away take the path to it. But if not? What happens then?

Comment: The machine will somehow report "no solution".